# Run Java Programs residing on server

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have uploaded a small java program (Hadoop Word Count) to a linux-server using FileZilla and now have to run that program onto server machine. I know how to connect to server using terminal i.e. `ssh -l user-name ip-of-server` But don't know how to run program that resides there. Please help me how to run that program from my machine.

Comment: Somewhat too broad, this inquiry is. We can't teach you the entire Linux command line system here,

Comment: @Fakhar -> you want to run any program or the Hadoop word count program?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get to the directory and run it. This is a short summary, and I ***strongly*** recommend you take a full tutorial.

You will first end up in your home directory. You can use `cd` to change to a subdirectory or `cd ..` to the parent:

```
cd tmp
```

and

```
cd ..
```

You can run a command in multiple ways. Invoke `java` as:

```
java ClassFile.class -cpPath1:path2
```

where Path1, path2, etc are classpath elements.

You can compile a .java to .class with:

```
javac File.java -args=blech
```

If a file is executable, use `./file` if in the same directory or `commandName` on the path.

Comment: your java command is wrong. you cannot run `.java` files. you need to compile them to `.class` files first.

Comment: @kw4nta The dummy filename was correct, and it should have been a class file.

Comment: please test before you write a command or be sure what you do. when running a `.class` files containing a main method, you must leave out the `.class`-fileending. Also there must be a space after -cp: `-cp_<classpath>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'd have to install java on the server, which can be done through your favorite package manager of your distribution, if you have `root` access. If not this is a little trickier, but it might allready be installed.

The class (e.g)

```
package my.mega.cool.pack;

public class MyMegaCoolClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("It's working... It's working!!!");
    }
}
```

Second of all, the question is, wether you uploaded a `.class` file or an (executable) jar.

(here you connect using ssh)

**If you** uploaded a `.class` file, you have to first `cd` (change directory, which is a unix command) to the base directory under which the package structure of the `.class` file is located.

1. Lets say, your class lies in package `my.mega.cool.pack` and is named `MyMegaCoolClass` and your base directory is `/home/you/mymegacooljavaprogram`.
2. This means that below your base directory you would have created (when uploading) the package structure: `my/mega/cool/pack` resulting in the complete file path:

   `/home/you/mymegacooljavaprogram/my/mega/cool/pack`
3. and the class would be located here: `/home/you/mymegacooljavaprogram/my/mega/cool/pack/MyMegaCoolClass.class`
4. This means you have to `cd` to `/home/you/mymegacooljavaprogram`
5. and run `java my.super.cool.package.MyMegaCoolClass`.

**If you** created an **executable** jar named `myMegaCoolSoftware.jar`, under the same base directory:

1. you have to `cd` to your base directory: `cd /home/you/mymegacooljavaprogram`
2. and run `java -jar myMegaCoolSoftware.jar`

**If you** created a **normal** jar,

1. the command looks like this

   `java -cp myMegaCoolSoftware.jar my.super.cool.package.MyMegaCoolClass`

e.g. you have to specify the jar file in the classpath.